# How do you put the feed from your blog in an app?

Tags: iphone, ios

I've never build an mobile App before and I want to create an iOS App for my blog. I'm wondering how do you put the feeds from my blog into the app?

Comment: Can you describe a little more about what you mean when you say put the feeds into your app? In all likelihood the feed is represented in as XML documents, and there are numerous options for parsing XML, but what you do with that XML depends on what you are trying to do.

Comment: What I meant was building a native app for my blog so that it will be easy for them to read the feeds. EX: When they press the a button, the blog posts shows up. The reason is because so many visitors visited my blog using their smart phone according to google analytics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well step number 1 is that you need to learn the basics of iOS development. I'm not sure of your background (programming/non-programming) but one thing for sure is that development for iOS is slightly different from most other platforms. That being said, there's a wealth of information to get started at http://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/

The right way is to go through the tutorials and documents.

Once you have a basic understanding of how to program for the iPhone, building a simple XML parser is really easy. All you need to do is point your app to your blog's RSS feed and parse that XML to display it on your app.

Apple has a sample XML parsing iPhone project here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SeismicXML/Introduction/Intro.html

Another way to do this if you don't have the patience to learn iOS programming is build a webapp using one of the many libraries available out there. My knowledge on this subject is limited so I guess I can point you in the right direction, and that is about it:
http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/

Comment: Right now, I know that I need a navigation bar at the bottom of the screen with four or five buttons and for each button pressed, there will be feeds coming in from, Twitter, Flickr, blog posts, youtube videos, etc. Since I'm new to iOS, this will be a challenge for me.  Thanks for pointing the directions...

Comment: You're welcome, and what you're thinking of is the UITabBarController and not a navigation bar... those are different :)